# Script stops executing if I remove alert()

Tags: jquery, events

```
$("div[id^='BlockHeading']").live("click", function () {

    var text = $(this).text().toString();
    if ($(this).next().css("display") == "none") {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).html("" + text + " <img src='../img/109041_25936_16_chevron_collapse_icon.png' height='12' width='12' style='float:right'>")
        iframeresize();
        $(this).focus();
    } else {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).html("" + text + " <img src='../img/109041_25936_16_chevron_collapse_iconDown.png' height='12' width='12' style='float:right'>")
        iframeresize();
        $(this).focus();
    }
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(100);
});
```

I am attempting to resize the `IFRAME` after an event has happened. The above shows one such event. The problem, though, occurs in the function `iframeresize()` - which is called if I fire an `alert()` before calling it, or within the function itself... and which works from the `debug-window` in Firebug - but does not work at all unless the `alert()` is present...

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
the code for `iframeresize()` :

```
function iframeresize() { 
     $("#frame1", parent.document).css("height", $("#form1").height() + 100);
     $("#container", parent.document).css("height", $("#form1").height() + 100); 
}
```

Comment: My guess is timing - can you try calling 'iframeresize' from inside the html you're inserting?

Comment: ok. let me try that one too..

Comment: sorry for asing but how do i do that...???

Comment: put a 'script' tag in the html, including code within it to call your function. techfoobar's answer below might be easier to try.

Comment: What's the `iframeresize` function? It's for sure some kind of timing problem.

Comment: Please don't use terms like does not work, it's sometimes completely unobvious what's wrong by just looking at code. Also, provide ALL relevant code instead of just this.

Comment: iframeresize just resizes the form height to the present iframe height

Comment: here's the snippet.. function iframeresize() {
            $("#frame1", parent.document).css("height", $("#form1").height() + 100);
            $("#container", parent.document).css("height", $("#form1").height() + 100);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it from a timeout and let the rest of the code continue execution.

```
...
setTimeout(iframeresize, 10);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i removed the `$(this).empty()` since anyway you assign new html to the element.
testing this code, proves that it works ( http://jsfiddle.net/Zt3eP/17/ )
so, there might be a problem with some other part of your code and not what you have displayed.

```
$("div[id^='BlockHeading']").live("click", function () {
    var text = $(this).text().toString();
    if ($(this).next().css("display") == "none") {
        $(this).html("" + text + " <img src='../img/109041_25936_16_chevron_collapse_icon.png' height='12' width='12' style='float:right'>")
        iframeresize();
        $(this).focus();
    } else {
        $(this).html("" + text + " <img src='../img/109041_25936_16_chevron_collapse_iconDown.png' height='12' width='12' style='float:right'>")
        iframeresize();
        $(this).focus();
    }
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(100);
});
function iframeresize(){
    console.log('resize');
}
​
```